# Page reload gives 404 not found in angular 6 when deployed on server

Tags: routes, angular6

I have a route named /explore in my angular . When run locally if i navigate to the route it displays does work and if i reload it reloads as well. I deployed the same code on ubuntu 16.04 server and used http-server to run it . The problem is if I click on the route it does navigate but if I reload the page it says "404 - Page not found." . A simple workaround i found out was to use "HashLocationStrategy" but it adds # to the url. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done already then add a .htaccess file to the root folder of your webserver (it's the folder where you deployed your app) with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

What happens here is you ask the webserver to return index.html on error - such as a 404 error. Angular will take over then and uses the routes that you set up in Angular.
I hope this helps but let me know if not.

Comment: I tried this solution i added the .htaccess file in dist folder after "ng build" ,it is still giving 404 after reload